# Component animation with transform react js

Tags: reactjs, css-animations

I try to build the game 2048 with react and redux-thunk.
I try to make an animation for the components.
I do get an animation but not the one I was looking for, my thinking is that the Cell component is getting unmount and mount again - so it doesn't make the animation I'm looking for.

The idea is that each cell have its position class for example :

```
class="cell cell__position--0-3 value-2"
```

when the user presses a button the class name change as well by the x,y position
this is the component file:

```
const Cell = (props) => {
// const cell = useSelector(state => state.cell);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

// useEffect(() => {
//     return () => null
// }, [props])

const cellClass = props.value ? `cell cell__position--${props.x}-${props.y} value-${props.value}` : `cell cell__position--${props.x}-${props.y} empty`

return (
    <div className={cellClass} key={props.key}>
        <div className='cell__init'>
            <div className="cell__value">
                {props.value}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

)
```

The animation that works seems to be about everything (like background color) but not the transition property.
is it because of the mount/unmount component? is there a solution?

**in case I wasn't clear - for example when the user press left the cell translate will change from translate(21vw, 0vw) to translate(0vw, 0vw) and slide all the way to its new place. from the previous state to a new state position.

[here is a short video of how it looks like.](https://monosnap.com/file/EHfVlPEwr3imnZmcJODx0LRLIYhY90)

[if the link above stops working - a youtube video](https://youtu.be/zN2bFOgHvdM)

Comment: I believe that main issue comes from un-mounting the component before the styles from the `className` have taken place. I would look into using an effect to set a `timeout` to allow for the styles in the `className` to render before unmounting the component.

Comment: yeah, I thought the same thing. thank you for the tip, will try it out